# Unrecognized argument to $dateFromString: onError MongoDB 3.6

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use onError argument in mongoDB's dateFromString , but getting following error :

**Unrecognized argument to $dateFromString: onError MongoDB 3.6**

Sample Code :

```
db.surgePrice.aggregate( [ {
$project: {
date: {
$dateFromString: {
dateString: '$date',
timezone: '$timezone',
onError: '$date'
}
}
}
} ] )
```

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to set the [`featureCompatibilityVersion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/#fields-conflicting-with-arrayfilters-identifiers) to **3.6**

Comment: Its already set to 3.6, still getting the same error!

Comment: Got it. `argument` **onError** has been added in mongodb version [**4.0**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) and you are using [**3.6**](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) Which doesn't have **onError** argument in `$dateFromString` aggregation. Either remove the **onError** or update to mongodb **4.0**

Comment: Thanks! MongoDb docs says onError has been added in 3.6.